# ReactJS - replacing an object in an array with another

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project where I have 4 options, but I should only be able to select one option per screen. The option pushes an object with an id and a score (based on the screen) to an array in the state. So if I make one selection and change to another, I'd like to able to remove the previous object and append the new one in an array in the state (for each screen). I have script to append and remove the object if I'm clicking on the same option, but I'm not sure what I would do to replace the object with a new one if I make a selection then immediately go to another.

The array looks as follows:

```
scores: [
  [{id: "G1", score: "4"}, {id: "B1", score: "3"}, {id: "O1", score: "2"}, {id: "R1", score: "1"}],
  [{id: "B2", score: "4"}, {id: "G2", score: "3"}, {id: "R2", score: "1"}, {id: "O2", score: "4"}]
]
```

Here is the code I have now:

```js
handleScore = (id, score, idx) => {
  const {
    statements,
    scores
  } = this.state;
  if (statements[0][idx].isSelected) {
    this.setState({
      scores: scores.map((item, index) => index === 0 ? [...item, {
        'id': id,
        'score': score
      }] : item)
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      scores: scores.map((item, index) => index === 0 ? item.filter(i => i.id !== item[0].id) : item)
    });
  }
}
```

and in the render method I have:

```
<div
  className={`statement ${(this.state.statements[0][index].isSelected) ? 'selected' : ''}`} key={item.id} onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.handleScore(item.id, match.params.score, index)
    }}>
  <a href="#">{item.statement}</a>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can use the `splice()` method to remove an item from an array. Check this [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bhr6zg?file=index.js) to see the result, and here is the code in case it does not works:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    {id: 0, score:10},
    {id: 1, score:20},
    {id: 2, score:30},
    {id: 3, score:40},
  ]);

const displayItems = () => {
  return data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
    <div>
      <span>id: {item.id}, score: {item.score}</span>{' '}
      <button onClick={() => replaceItem(item, index)}>Replace item</button>
    </div>
  )});
}

const replaceItem = (item, index) => {
  const newItem = {id:4, score: 50};

  let newData = [...data]; 

  // -----Replace ONE ('1') item at specific index by the newItem
  // newData.splice(index, 1, newItem); 
  // -----OR remove an item and place another at the first index
  newData.splice(index, 1); // remove item from array
  newData.unshift(item); // Put the item at the first index of the array
  //------
  setData(newData); // set your newData array as the new state
}
  return (
    <div>
      {displayItems()}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I placed two use case of splice so you can coment/uncomment to see the result.

Comment: I figured it out and your response helped a lot. I was making this way more difficult than it needed to be. All I needed to do is check if there is something in the array, and if there is, splice it out. Ugh. Thank you so much!!!